# Compare 2 arrays/lists and print differences

Tags: knockout.js

I have a total of 4 lists. `storedProceduresInDB1`, `storedProceduresInDB2`, `missingStoredProcedureInDB1` and `missingStoredProcedureInDB2`.

I want to compare `storedProceduresInDB1` and `storedProceduresInDB2`. 
The items contained in `storedProceduresInDB1` but not in `storedProceduresInDB2` I want to add in `missingStoredProcedureInDB2` and vice versa because i only want to print items in `missingStoredProcedureInDB1` and `missingStoredProcedureInDB2` and not added, deleted etc.

As it is now, it adds all items from `storedProceduresInDB1` and `storedProceduresInDB2` into both 
`missingStoredProcedureInDB1` and `missingStoredProcedureInDB2`.

Is this possible with `ko.utils.compareArrays` or is there a better approach doing this?

Thank you!

EDIT: Improved explanation and updated jsfiddle.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zp5K/22/

Comment: please add some code to your post to highlight where the issue is and any errors that you see. Might also be better to provide a cut down fiddle to show the issue.

Comment: Did you look at here http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html, It has a status property. I think, you can use it

Comment: @sinanakyazici Yes i've looked at that example.

Comment: console shows: value is not defined: line 43: `return value === item;` so it won't get past that

Comment: you're over complicating things trying to use that fiddle, try to create a simple example to highlight your issue, start with this: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/42xGX/2/

Comment: I've updated my jsfiddle. It doesnt complain about any error now, but does not work as i wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking an example of comparing two arrays using a `dependantObservable` from [knockmeout.net utility-functions](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html), I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zp5K/24/

**Code:**

Compare function simply does the logging:

```
self.compare = function () {
   console.log('items missing in database1', self.missingInDb1());
   console.log('items missing in database2', self.missingInDb2());
};
```

Two `dependentObservable` setup to perform the comparison:

```
self.missingInDb1 = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    var differences = ko.utils.compareArrays(
                     self.storedProceduresInDB2(), self.storedProceduresInDB1());
    //return a flat list of differences
    var results = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(differences, function (difference) {
        if (difference.status === "deleted") {
            results.push(difference.value);
        }
    });        
    return results;
})

self.missingInDb2 = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    var differences = ko.utils.compareArrays(
                     self.storedProceduresInDB1(), self.storedProceduresInDB2());
    //return a flat list of differences
    var results = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(differences, function (difference) {
        if (difference.status === "deleted") {
            results.push(difference.value);
        }
    });        
    return results;
})
```